# How many days of interest do I lose if I make a wire transfer from one bank to another?

Tags: united-states, interest, wire-transfer

I suppose this will depend on the banks, so what's typical?  Do any banks do this in 0 days?  What's the longest which would still be allowed by law?

Both bank accounts are already established and in my name, and suppose I initiate the transfer at 10 am.

Comment: Relatively, does it matter much? If you move $10K earning a fantastic 3% to another bank, you lose out on 82 cents a day...

Comment: At least an order of magnitude less than the wire transfer fee.

Answer (score 1):

Anything betwen 0 and days, possibly some to a week.

Depends on banks and what you pay. I have had Wires with Telex Avies credited within 20 minutes 25 years ago, so - it definitely is possible. Expect to PAY.